# C# Insert Picture into Ms Access

Tags: c#, database, image, insert

I would like to thanks to all who helped in last question.
but now, i have problem with another statement which is saveimageto MS access.
First, I would like to ask, on ms access database, Datatype should put attachment?

my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (id,picture) values ('" + textBox1.Text +  "')";

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Created", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            con.Close();

        }
```

I insert my picture to picturebox using openFIledialog.

Comment: Hi Tham JunKai, 
can you please specify what the problem is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, use parameters. NEVER concat strings for SQL commands, as it opens itself to SQL Injection. That's an easy to follow good practice that'll avoid you a lot of trouble in the future.

That said, something like this should work:

```
// You've got the filename from the result of your OpenDialog operation
var pic = File.ReadAllBytes(yourFileName);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (id, picture) values (@p1, @p2)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", pic);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Citing from memory here, but let me know if that code gives you trouble. If I remember correctly, something like that should work.

EDIT.- If you're preloading the image on a PictureBox control, convert that image to a byte array and then use that byte array as the second parameter.

EDIT (2).- A little clarification. If you're are getting your image from a file, you have a path to it; then you can use `File.ReadAllBytes(string path)`. In my example I was assuming that `yourFileName` was the file and path name of the selected file after a successful `OpenDialog` operation. So you can use it like this:

```
byte[] fromPath = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\walls\aurora.jpg");
```

and you'd store into the byte array fromPath the image, converted to bytes and ready to be used in an insertion command as seen above.

**BUT** if you're getting your image from a picture box control, things are a little different:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] fromControl = ms.GetBuffer();
```

In that example I've created a `MemoryStream`, filled it with the content of the picturebox control and then passed it to the byte array, and again we're ready to use it as a parameter for our insertion query.

Oh, don't forget to add

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
```

to your usings.

Comment: Hello yourFileName means? do you have teamviewer, so i can ask you easier.?

Comment: var pic = File.ReadAllBytes(pictureBox1); can be used like this?