# Trying to save an image to Access: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO"

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2010

I hope someone can help me with this I am trying to save an image from a picturebox to an access database, I have set the data type of the field to "OLEDB" and am using the following code, the error message I am getting states there is a Syntax error in the INSERT INTO string, I am very new to doing anything beyond storing text values and dates in a database from C#, if anyone can help it would be appreciated.

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                      
    {

        string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
        Conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon);

        DateTime dateLastSvc = Convert.ToDateTime(txtLastService.Text);            
        DateTime datePAT = Convert.ToDateTime(txtPatTest.Text);
        DateTime dateSvcCal = Convert.ToDateTime(lblNextSvcCalc.Text);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pbxEquipmentImage.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] pbxAray = ms.GetBuffer();

        Comm = new OleDbCommand();
        Comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Equipment(SerialNumber, DeviceName, LotNo, Critical, ISO, ServiceInterval, LastService, PAT, Location, Supplier, ServiceProvider, Comments, NextService, Image, FilePath) VALUES (@Serial, @Device,@Lot, @Critical, @ISO, @SvcInt, @LastSvc, @PAT, @Location, @Supplier, @SvcProv, @Comments, @NextSvc, @photo, @Link)";

        //Comm = new OleDbCommand(strSql, Conn);            
        //ms.Position = 0;
        //ms.Read(pbxAray, 0, pbxAray.Length);
        //pbxAray = ms.ToArray();

        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", txtSerialNumber.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Device", txtDeviceName.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lot", txtLotNumber.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Critical", cbxCritical.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISO", cbxISOcert.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SvcInt", txtServiceInterval.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastSvc", dateLastSvc);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAT", datePAT);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", cbxLocation.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", cbxSupplier.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SvcProv", cbxServiceProvider.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", txtComments.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextSvc", lblNextSvcCalc.Text);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", pbxAray);
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Link", linkFilePath.Text);

        Conn.Open();
        try                                                                                                     
        {                
            Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();                                                                             
            MessageBox.Show("The record has been added to the database");
            Conn.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)                                                                                  
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not save the information due to: " + ex.Message);                               
            Conn.Close();
        }
        finally                                                                                                 
        {
            txtSerialNumber.Clear();                                                                          
            txtDeviceName.Clear();                                                                            
            txtLotNumber.Clear();                                                                             
            cbxCritical.Text = "Please Select";                                                                 
            cbxISOcert.Text = "Please Select";                                                                  
            txtServiceInterval.Clear();                                                                       
            txtLastService.Text = null;                                                                           
            txtPatTest.Text = null;                                                                               
            cbxLocation.Text = "Please Select";                                                                 
            cbxSupplier.Text = "Please Select";                                                                 
            cbxServiceProvider.Text = "Please Select";                                                          
            txtComments.Clear();                                                                              
            lblNextSvcCalc.Text = null;                                                                           
            pbxEquipmentImage.Image = null;                                                                     
            linkFilePath.Text = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273617/c-sharp-insert-picture-into-ms-access. Also take note of the advice of not using string concatenation to create sql statements. I could put some nasty text into one of those textboxes and cause your system all sorts of problems.

Comment: Hello Mashton thank you for the link I have changed my code accordingly but still it will not work I have edited my code above.

Comment: sorry meant to say it throws an error at the Comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IMAGE` is a [reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx#_Toc272229040) in Access SQL, so in order to reference that field in your table you need to enclose the field name in square brackets. That is, in your `CommandText` you need to replace

```
... NextService, Image, FilePath ...
```

with

```
... NextService, [Image], FilePath ...
```

.

p.s. - I think you also want to replace

```csharp
Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextSvc", lblNextSvcCalc.Text);
```

with

```csharp
Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextSvc", dateSvcCal);
```

Comment: thank you for the tip it worked but only after I tweaked the code to run the INSERT INTO statement in the command statement with the connection at the end as follows - Comm = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Equipment(*****, *****, *****, NextService, [Image], FilePath) VALUES (*****, *****, *****, NextSvc, @photo, Link)", Conn); - just need to recall the image now back to the picturebox, many thanks for your help.